# Trying to rebase/rename 30 commits on GitHub

Tags: git

I was recently switched from using Cloud9 (as student on a course) to AWS student, and as a result of the migration, my username got mixed up.
I created a new repository and cloned the one I had been working on in Cloud9.
Although AWS is working fine, I stupidly overlooked about 30 commits that weren't being contributed to my GitHub account, and were showing as 'Ubuntu' (not my GitHub Username).

I looked on Stack Overflow and found a very helpful post to rebase author name [`git commit -m --amend --author="username email@example.com"`].
Having followed up on this, I merged the current repository with my username and currently anything I push to GitHub is in my username.

However, I've still got 30 commits saying they were committed by 'Ubuntu' and not by me, so I am trying to rename/rebase all of these.

Is it possible to do this in a range (ie) `aafabaa...7652e29`, rather than individually rebase each commit?
I know it's a lot of commits to rebase and maybe not possible to do it all at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, working on a range of commits is what describes the GitHUb help page "[Changing author info](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-author-info)"

It uses [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), which can use a range, as specified by [rev-list](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list).

But you will then need to `git push --force` to AWS, in order to overwrite your new history.

Comment: Many thanks for your helpful answer. Will try this.

Comment: oops sorry..not all that used to stack overflow. I will go back to other answer. I just select it again as right?

Answer (score 0):

30 commits is still doable manually using [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History). Look at the section 'Changing Multiple Commit Messages'. Give you more control and therefore is safer than some scripts floating around the web.

Comment: Many thanks, I will accept this answer, over first, even though both answers are very helpful, as it carries less risk. I have to submit the project I'm doing by next week however and doubt I will be able to have time to look more into interactive rebase. Will carry on and submit and explain what happened, so at least it accounts for why the commits aren't under my name. Will still look into interactive rebase however. Thanks for the help. Much appreciated.